# RefineryCMS admin functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I have never worked with a CMS before so this is all new to me and I need some advice. This is for RefineryCMS.

I need to create an admin only page that will allow an admin user to run ruby code, i.e. a gem or custom functionality, in the back ground. This is more for maintenance purposes for the client to run. How do I add a page to the admin backend that will let me add buttons that will run custom rake tasks or run code from a gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a page for this, you just need to route to a custom controller that does what you want.. just using plain Rails. Just make sure you route to your action before you mount Refinery::Core::Engine or else it will take over with its wildcard routing.

Comment: You are correct. I started down that path but had my rout below the `mount Refinery::Core::Engine` and just figured it out. Thanks for the reply.